# Substring Statement

Tags: sql-server

I am using a SQL substring statement to return periods after a Middle Name initial, such as, "H."  When there is no Middle name to return, the period still returns in a field that should be null.

Here is my statement:

```
substring([Middle Name],1,1)+('.')
```

Answer (score 3):

As `NULL + anything == NULL` how  about:

```
select left(nullif([Middle Name], ''), 1) + '.'
```

Or

```
select case when [Middle Name] is not null then left([Middle Name], 1) + '.' end
```

Comment: Yes!  That was the ticket.  It worked great.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
substring(nullif([Middle Name], ''), 1, 1) + '.'
```

You may check the [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177562.aspx)

> Returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.